# Problema con pivot SQL server 2008 r2

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

Buenas gente,

no he tocado mucho el tema del sql, al menos para hacer esto que me ha pedido un cliente, necesita crear una vista donde se vea una sola línea con los días de un mes que introduzca un usuario de su aplicativo y muestre ciertos datos.

tengo esta consulta que funciona muy bien

```
    SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT 
       left(datename(day,DATEFIELD),3)as [day],
        FIELD1 AS FIELD1
    FROM dbo.TABLEFROMDDBB
    WHERE FIELD2 = 0 
    AND FIELD1 = 0
    AND DATEFIELD between '01/06/2017 00:00:00' AND '30/06/2017 23:59:00'
    AND FIELD3 = 'xxx'
    AND FIELD4 = 123456789
    AND FIELD5 = 'xxxx'
) as s
PIVOT
(
    COUNT(FIELD1)
    FOR [day] IN ([1], [2], [3], [4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],
[11],[12],[13],[14],[15],[16],[17],[18],[19],[20],
[21],[22],[23],[24],[25],[26],[27],[28],[29],[30])
)AS pvt
```

Lo que necesito es meter esta otra consulta justo en el "FOR [day] IN" del pivot para que me muestre los dias del mes especifico (con año incluido) en la tabla resultante, este es el resto del código que he creado:

```
    DECLARE @month TINYINT        
SET @month = MONTH('01/12/2017 00:00:00');
WITH
CTE_Days AS
(
SELECT DATEADD(month, @month , DATEADD(month, -MONTH(GETDATE()), DATEADD(day, -DAY(GETDATE())
+ 1, CAST(FLOOR(CAST(GETDATE() AS FLOAT)) AS datetime)))) D
UNION ALL
SELECT DATEADD(day, 1, D)
FROM CTE_Days
WHERE D < DATEADD(day, -1, DATEADD(month, 1, DATEADD(month, @month, DATEADD(month, -MONTH(GETDATE()),
DATEADD(day, -DAY(GETDATE()) + 1, CAST(FLOOR(CAST(GETDATE() AS FLOAT)) AS DATETIME))))))
)
SELECT DAY(d) AS Days_Of_Week
FROM CTE_Days
```

Quien dice meter esta consulta dice que se aceptan soluciones a ver si consigo sacar esto para adelante, agradezco cualquier ayuda que me podáis prestar.

Muchas gracias de antebrazo :)

EDITO:

He tratado de crear un sql dinámico:

```
DECLARE @cols AS VARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @date1 AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @date2 AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

    set @date1 = '01/06/2017'
    set @date2 = '30/06/2017'

;WITH
CTE_Days AS
(
SELECT DATEADD(month, 06, DATEADD(month, -MONTH(GETDATE()), DATEADD(day, -DAY(GETDATE())
+ 1, CAST(FLOOR(CAST(GETDATE() AS FLOAT)) AS datetime)))) D
UNION ALL
SELECT DATEADD(day, 1, D)
FROM CTE_Days
WHERE D < DATEADD(day, -1, DATEADD(month, 1, DATEADD(month, 06, DATEADD(month, -MONTH(GETDATE()),
DATEADD(day, -DAY(GETDATE()) + 1, CAST(FLOOR(CAST(GETDATE() AS FLOAT)) AS DATETIME)))))))



SELECT @cols = 'SELECT DAY(d) AS Days_Of_Week FROM CTE_Days'


SET @query = 'SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT 
       left(datename(day,DATEFIELD),3)as [day],
        FIELD1 AS FIELD1
    FROM dbo.TABLEFROMDDBB
    WHERE FIELD2 = 0 
    AND FIELD1 = 0
    AND DATEFIELD between ' + @date1 + ' AND ' + @date2 + ' 
     AND FIELD3 = ''xxx''
    AND FIELD4 = 123456789
    AND FIELD5 = ''xxxx''
) as s
PIVOT
(
    COUNT(xrealizado_sn)
    FOR [day] IN (' + @cols + ')
)AS pvt'

execute(@query)
```

pero me arroja el siguiente error, que por mas que he buscado en Don Google no he sacado nada en claro:

> Expresión de tabla común definida pero no utilizada.

Agradezco cualquier ayuda que me podais brindar, compañeros.

Muchas gracias de antebrazo :)

Answer (score 0):

Al final, después de darle mas vueltas que una Noria he sacado una consulta que, al menos a mí me funciona:

```
    DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @date1 AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @date2 AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @space NVARCHAR (10),
    @x NVARCHAR (10) 

    set @date1 = '''01/06/2013'''
    set @date2 = '''30/06/2013'''
    set @space = ''''''
    set @x = '''X'''

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(DAY(a.FECHA))
                    from dbo.CALENDARIO AS a
                    WHERE a.FECHA between @date1 AND @date2 
                    group by a.FECHA
                    order by a.FECHA
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')
        ,1,1,'')

SET @query = 'SELECT pvt.*
FROM (
    SELECT 
       left(datename(day,DATEFIELD),3)as [day],
        FIELD1 AS FIELD1
    FROM dbo.TABLEFROMDDBB
    WHERE FIELD2 = 0 
    AND FIELD1 = 0
    AND DATEFIELD between ' + @date1 + ' AND ' + @date2 + ' 
    AND FIELD3 = 'xxx'
    AND FIELD4 = 123456789
    AND FIELD5 = 'xxxx'
) as s
PIVOT
(
    COUNT(FIELD1)
    FOR [day] IN (' + @cols + ')
)AS pvt' 

execute(@query);
```

Creé una tabla Calendario donde le inserté TODAS las fechas desde el 2000 hasta el 3000 (DD/MM/YYYY) de donde saco los datos de los días del mes elegido y después hago el pivot, solo lo he conseguido con un sql dinámico, pero ahora se me presentan otros problemas para los cuales abriré otro hilo a ver si consigo ayuda o consejo, que son siempre bienvenidos.

Espero que si alguien tiene este problema le sirva.